# Android, AsyncTask but UiThread still laggy

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am creating a Jewel like game for android, however my problem is that the game is very laggy, I tried creating an AsyncTask to reduce the pressure on the UIthread, it helped but it's still too laggy to play it, any tips on how I should change my code?  I also tried creating Two different arrayList of ImageView to reduce time in the for loops : liste_rubies and liste_rubies_falling.  Basically they have to stop falling once they touch another ruby and stack unto one another, it works but it's way too laggy past a certain number of rubies on the board.  Thanks for your answers

```
public boolean TestColisions(ImageView Ruby){
    boolean test = false;
    Rect Rect_tempo = new Rect();
    Ruby.getHitRect(Rect_tempo);
    for(int y=0;y<liste_Rubies.size();y++){
        if(liste_Rubies.get(y).getY() != Ruby.getY()){
    Rect Rect_tempo2 = new Rect();
    liste_Rubies.get(y).getHitRect(Rect_tempo2);
     Rect_tempo2.set( Rect_tempo2.left,  (int) (Rect_tempo2.top),  Rect_tempo2.right,  Rect_tempo2.bottom);
        if (Rect.intersects(Rect_tempo2, Rect_tempo)) {
        test = true;
        liste_Rubies.remove(y);
        if(Ruby.getY()<H10)
        MessageVictoire();
        }
        }
    }
    return test;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------MoveDown V2 --
private class MoveDownV2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ArrayList<ImageView>liste_Rubies, liste_Rubies_falling;
    public MoveDownV2(ArrayList<ImageView>liste_Rubies, ArrayList<ImageView>liste_Rubies_falling) {
        this.liste_Rubies = liste_Rubies;
        this.liste_Rubies_falling = liste_Rubies_falling;

        String launch = doInBackground();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        MoveDown=new Timer();
           MoveDown.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


        for(int x = 0; x < liste_Rubies_falling.size(); x++){
            float tempo = liste_Rubies_falling.get(x).getY();


            if(liste_Rubies_falling.get(x).getY() < H10*7 && !TestColisions(liste_Rubies_falling.get(x))){
                liste_Rubies_falling.get(x).setY(tempo+50);}
            else{liste_Rubies.add(liste_Rubies_falling.get(x));
                liste_Rubies_falling.remove(liste_Rubies_falling.get(x));}
                        }
        LeCounter++;
        if(LeCounter%17==0){
            RubyPopUp();

                      }
                }  
             }, 82, 82);   
    return null;
    }       
 }

public void RubyPopUp() {
    SpartanRuby.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
    ImageView Ruby = new ImageView(context);
    Ruby.setX((float) (L10*5));
    Ruby.setY(0);
    Ruby.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY); 
    Ruby.setImageResource(R.drawable.rubies_rouge);
    RubyTest = Ruby;
    liste_Rubies_falling.add(Ruby);
    liste_Rubies_total.add(Ruby);
    ((ViewGroup) layout_spartanruby).addView(Ruby);
    SetSize(Ruby);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Any small tip that can reduce lag will be appreciated even if it's just by a little!